# Dropshadow with css

Tags: css, opacity, dropshadow

I want to add a transparent dropshadow to my div. I have a container, and behind it I want to place a dropshadow. I don't want the dropshadow to have a color. This is what I have so far:

```
.content_right1{

    background:#fff;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius:10px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #99CCFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #99CCFF ;
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #99CCFF;

    /* other styles of the class */
    width:380px;
    float:left;

    margin-left:3px;
    padding:15px;

    min-height:450px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

I want to add the opacity, but when I do the opacity of the whole div changes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can a dropshadow not have any colour?  Do you mean monochromatic (black/white only)?  It not, do you have an example of the effect?

Comment: You want a non-coloured drop-shadow? If it has no colour it won't be seen, so...could you explain, a little more clearly, what you want? And what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The `opacity` style property is meant to affect the opacity of the element(s) it's applied to, not an effect applied to the element.

Comment: An attempt at a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zCTC8/

Answer (score 43):

If you want a dropshadow with a level of opacity, you should use rgba() for its shadow color :

http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/

edit:

```
-moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Comment: drop-shadow != box-shadow

Answer (score 2):

While your question is ultimately a little opaque (pun intended), does the following do what you are expecting?

```
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dddddd;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dddddd;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #dddddd;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zCTC8/2/

All I essentially did was adjust the *color* value of the shadow, which is the last value in the declaration (`#dddddd`, or `#ddd`). These are hex values. See here for more examples:

http://html-color-codes.com/

`#ddd`/`#dddddd` represents a light grey color; `#eee` is lighter, `#ccc` is darker, `#fff` is white, and `#000` is black. The value `#000` represents `RGB`, with valid values of 0-9A-F (dark->light), so that:

```
#f00 = red (R)
#0f0 = green (G)
#00f = blue (B)
```

The value `#99CCFF` [from your question](http://jsfiddle.net/zCTC8/) is equivalent to `#9CF`, which gives a middle red (9), a light green (C), and white (F). The mix of these values gives you the light blue shade you were seeing, which is why you were getting a color instead of a "shadow-like" color (gray shade).

My color theory is a little rusty here, so anyone correct me if I've flubbed something.